# How to populate a table td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a table and I need to populate the `tds` using JavaScript because the data is coming from the server.
Here is my table:

```
<table id="report" class="infoRecurso" id='testExportId' style="width: 100%; color: #363636">
<thead style="color: #363636">
    <tr class='btn-danger' style="background-color: lightgray; color: #363636">
        <th class="thData">Data</th>
        <th id="timeIniticial" class="thInicio">Início</th>
        <th class="thTermino">Término</th>
        <th class="thDuracao">Duração</th>
        <th class="thAtividades">Atividades</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left;"></td>>
        <td id="inicialTime"></td>
        <td>Hora Final</td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">Duração</td>
        <td colspan="1" class="quebraLinha" style="text-align: left;"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="horasTotaisTh" colspan="3"> Horas Totais </th>
        <th class="resultadoHorasTotaisTh" colspan="4">Hora Total</th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am trying to populate the `td`  with the id inicialTime that is corresponding to the `tr` timeIniticial. I've tried using this code:

```
var data = [{"product": "RD0"}, {"product": "RD1-184"}, {"product": "RD1-185"}];
var table = $('.infoRecurso');
$.each(data, function(i, value) {
    table.find('tr').eq(i).find("td[id='inicialTime']").text(value.product);
});
```

but this code only populates the first position.

How can I populate the rest of `tds` positions?

Comment: Ids are meant to be unique on the page, if you need to interact with multiple elements you should use a css class instead and use a selector to retrieve all td with the class name, this will give you a list of nodes you can loop through and apply your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves a few points open, so I can only guess what you *really* want. In the following snippet I have compiled a solution that will `.prepend()` some html code to your table, to the effect that your second column is always filled with the code from your data array. I changed the `id` attribute of this `<td>` element to `class` since IDs must always be unique.

I also "corrected" your colspan attributes of the last table row since there are only 5 columns in total.

```js
var data = [{"product": "RD0"}, {"product": "RD1-184"}, {"product": "RD1-185"}];

var html=data.map(({product})=>
`<tr><td></td><td class="inicialTime">${product}</td><td>Hora Final</td>
 <td>Duração</td><td class="quebraLinha"></td></tr>`).join('')

$('.infoRecurso tbody').prepend(html);
```

```css
 td {text-align:left}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="report" class="infoRecurso" id='testExportId' style="width: 100%; color: #363636">
<thead style="color: #363636">
    <tr class='btn-danger' style="background-color: lightgray; color: #363636">
        <th class="thData">Data</th>
        <th class="thInicio">Início</th>
        <th class="thTermino">Término</th>
        <th class="thDuracao">Duração</th>
        <th class="thAtividades">Atividades</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="myTable">
 <tr>
   <th class="horasTotaisTh" colspan="3"> Horas Totais </th>
   <th class="resultadoHorasTotaisTh" colspan="2">Hora Total</th>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```